# Formatting 11/16/2002 12:00:00 PM to date time stamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.0

How do I change this format "`11/16/2002 12:00:00 PM`" to something that MySQL will understand **without** using PHP?

I've tried   `SELECT CONVERT('11/03/2002 02:45:33 PM', DATETIME) AS datetime;` and I just get NULL

Comment: please edit question to include your attempt and any error message(s) you're getting. thank you

Comment: @bernie I added code but doesn't work.

Comment: @AmitBhargava , added what I've tried with convert

Comment: @Brad SELECT CONVERT('2002-03-11 14:45:33', DATETIME) AS datetime works. Can you modify your date string slightly?

Comment: @Amit Bhargava: this is what question about ;-) How to reformat it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function -

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/03/2002 02:45:33 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') AS dt;
+---------------------+
| dt                  |
+---------------------+
| 2002-03-11 14:45:33 |
+---------------------+
```

or

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11/03/2002 02:45:33 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %r') AS dt;
+---------------------+
| dt                  |
+---------------------+
| 2002-03-11 14:45:33 |
+---------------------+
```